# Proxy model edit/add missing on Foreign Key fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-apps

**Goal**:
I want to group some of my models inside of other apps on the Admin page.

**How**:
I created a proxy model for each of my models and defined `app_label` to be that of the app I want.

```
class MyModelProxy(MyModel):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = 'auth' # specify a different app for the model to be grouped with
        verbose_name = MyModel._meta.verbose_name
        verbose_name_plural = MyModel._meta.verbose_name_plural
```

I registered the proxy model together with the custom admin model I created for each.

```
admin.site.register(MyModelProxy, MyModelAdmin)
```

**Issue 1:**
My Foreign Key fields lose the icons to edit/add another object in the view/change pages. If I register the original model with the admin model, it displays fine.

[image: Without proxy model] (original)--> (proxy)
[image: With proxy model]

**Issue 2:**
If I set `autocomplete_fields` inside the corresponding admin models, I get an error that the original model should be registered. But I want to only register the proxy model, not both ?